# How to select quarter for current year by number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to have method like

```
Shift.by_quarter(1) => each shift in first quarter of current year
```

Right now I am selecting a quarter shifts by date

```
Shift
  scope :by_quarter, lambda{|date| 
    where starts_at: date.beginning_of_quarter..date.end_of_quarter}
```

Comment: You'd want the by_quarter to filter the Shift returned data set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my solution:

```
scope :by_quarter, lambda{|quarter| 
    date = Date.new(Date.today.year, quarter * 3)
    where starts_at: date.beginning_of_quarter..date.end_of_quarter }
```